# Removing div rows which have same class identifiers dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to remove a div row by clicking Delete but the problem is all the rows have same class name so I don't know how to individually remove the rows.

```
<div class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableRow">

        <div class="divTableCell">
            ROW 1
        </div>

        <div class="divTableCell">
            <span class="delete-size-row">DELETE</span>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">

        <div class="divTableCell">
            ROW 2
        </div>

        <div class="divTableCell">
            <span class="delete-size-row">DELETE</span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I can do something like this but this has unique identifiers so it won't work for me. I need a dynamic solution.

```
$(".delete-size-row").click(function() {
        $('#removeRow-unique').hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find parent div with class `divTableRow` then you can hide it.

*Code*

```
$(".delete-size-row").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.divTableRow').hide();
});
```

In event handler `this` refers to element which invoked the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this

```
$(".delete-size-row").click(function() {
    $(this).parents('div.divTableRow').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".delete-size-row").click(function() {        
     $(this).closest('.divTableRow').hide();     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use parent function, and then hide it :) 
Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cv28n/

```
   $(".delete-size-row").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });
```

Hope it may help you. Thanks and have a nice day. :)